# How to make generic stringToVector function in c++?

Tags: c++, generics, vector

I am trying to make a generic stringToVector function.

The input is a string that contains multiple int or string separated by comma (let's ignore char)

ex)
[1, 5, 7] or [conver, to, string, vector]

I want a generic function like this

```
template <class T>
vector<T> stringToVector(string input) {
    vector<T> output;
    input = input.substr(1, input.length() - 2);

    stringstream ss;
    ss.str(input);
    T item;
    char delim = ',';
    while (getline(ss, item, delim)) {
        if (is_same(T, int)) {
            output.push_back(stoi(item));    // error if T is string
        } else {
            output.push_back(item);          // error if T is int
        }
    }

    return output;
}
```

Is there any way around?

I know this function is dumb, but I just want this for a competitive programming.

Comment: You already have `stringstream` which can extract `T` why do you use `getline`? Just do `ss>>item;`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-do-i-iterate-over-the-words-of-a-string

Comment: @Slava -- because the input operation has to respect comma as a field separator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually it is done by a helper function:

```
template<class T>
T my_convert( std::string data );

template<>
std::string my_convert( std::string data )
{
    return data;
}

template<>
int my_convert( std::string data )
{
    return std::stoi( data );
}
```

inside your function:

```
str::string str;
while (getline(ss, str, delim))
   output.push_back( my_convert<T>( std::move( str ) ) );
```

it will fail to compile for any other type than `std::string` or `int` but you can add more specializations of `my_convert` if you need to support other types.

Comment: You forgot to include the template parameters in front of your specializations. e.g. `template <> std::string my_convert<string>(std::string data)`, `template <> int my_convert<int>(std::string data)`

Comment: @J.Willus actually this is a good point, but gcc 8.3.0 hapily compiles it without explicit definition